# How to delete strings to close quote and close parenthese

Tags: cut-copy-paste, insert-mode

I have a code like this:

```
h5 style=("text-align: center; margin-top: 2rem;") some text
p style=("text-align: center; margin-top: 2rem;") some text
```

And in first line, I want to delete  `margin-top: 2rem;`, so the result will look like this:

```
h5 style=("text-align: center;") some text
p style=("text-align: center; margin-top: 2rem;") some text
```

Currently I am using `x` to delete or `dw` to delete each text but it seems not a good idea, do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's indeed more straight-forward ways to do this.

As you can see in the help for `:h d`

```
                            *d*
["x]d{motion}       Delete text that {motion} moves over [into register
            x].  See below for exceptions.
```

The `delete` command, as many, accepts a motion. This means you can tell Vim what object you want to delete (`diw` for "delete inner word", `dap` for "delete around paragraph...).

In your case, `dt;` seems to be appropriate: it will **d**elete from the cursor position un**t**il (not including) the next `;`.

`df;` will do the same, but including the `;`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`f`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#f) or [`t`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#f) motions for this. With your cursor at the start of the text you want to delete:

```
 h5 style=("text-align: center; margin-top: 2rem;") some text
                               ^
```

Type either of these:

```
df;
dt"
```

The first deletes up to and including the `;` character, the second deletes up to but not including the `"`.

See [`:help 03.3`](https://vimhelp.org/usr_03.txt.html#03.3) for more details.